# how to use fiddler to make Post request

Tags: http-post, fiddler

I have capured the Post request from Fiddler , now i wanted to re execute this Post reqest from Fiddler itself.

Please suggest me steps to re execute the Post request from fiddler

I am using Fiddler4

Thanks

Comment: You drag the request to the composer tab. Try searching.

Answer (score 0):

You can reissue requests in Fiddler in many ways. For instance, you can simply right-click any Session in the Web Sessions list and choose `Replay` from the context menu. Alternatively, you can drag and drop a Session to the `Composer` tab and edit it before resending.